# Google Apps Script - API Xml foi suspensa

Tags: javascript, google, parse

Possuo um script Google Apps Script porém passei a receber o seguinte erro:

> A API Xml foi suspensa.
>   **A API foi marcada como reprovada, o que significa que o recurso deve ser evitado e poderá ser removido posteriormente. Considere usar outra
>   solução.**

Abaixo trecho do código:

```
var xmldocument = Xml.parse(xmlContent, true);
var items = xmldocument.rss.channel.getElements("item");

for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {        
    var jiraKey  = items[index].getElement("key").getText();
```

Alterei o parse passando a utilizar o  `var xmldocument = XmlService.parse(xmlContent);` porém passei a receber o seguinte erro:

> TypeError: Cannot read property "channel" from undefined. (linha 185, arquivo "Jira Validation"

Alguém sabe a melhor solução para esse problema?

Obrigado.

Comment: A melhor solução é parar de usar XML, conforme o aviso, e trocar pelo formato mais moderno e prático que eles sugerirem. Não que vc não possa arrumar a propriedade com problema, que nao deve ter a ver com o aviso de cima, mas já podia resolver de uma vez.